# How to install a gem so that it executes independent of currently active RVM gemset?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I am writing a dev command-line tool gem (let's say called "tool") which I would like to use in any place in the system. I use RVM for different projects, but this tool should be available from the command-line inside those projects.

If I simply install the gem globally using "gem install" (let's say it installs to /usr/local/bin/tool), the executable is of course available inside of other projects, but since the gemset changed when executing "tool" it fails saying that it cannot find the "tool" gem (because "tool" was never installed to that gemset). I don't want to add the gem to all the Gemfiles of all the projects.

What's the best way of dealing with this? Perhaps there is a way to "lock" the gem_path/gem_home in the executable at the time of installation?

Comment: I see at least one option is to wrap the executable call in "env -i" as described here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48994/how-to-run-a-program-in-a-clean-environment-in-bash .

Comment: "but since the gemset changed when executing "tool" it fails saying that it cannot find the "tool" gem (because "tool" was never installed to that gemset)" - What do you mean with that?

"I don't want to add the gem to all the Gemfiles of all the projects." - If you need the tool within a project, it should be added to the Gemfile imo.

Comment: @Hardy I am talking about  a system-wide command, e.g. something that might have been installed using brew. Only it happens to be a gem. Hmm, maybe https://github.com/sportngin/brew-gem will do the trick, will check...

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that https://github.com/sportngin/brew-gem does what I want, installing a Rubygems gem via brew and locking its GEM_HOME and GEM_PATH in a bin wrapper it generates, so that everything works even when executed in the context of a different RVM gemset.

I forked it into https://github.com/gtmax/brew-gem, adding support for installing a brew gem from a local.gem file or from a gem project on github.